# Ubuntu 20.04, Nvidia GTX 1660 Super screen flickering

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, flicker

*It seems like the problem is there only with Scaling set to 200%. If I use Fractional scaling and set 150% or 175%, there is no flickering. However, I dislike that that way the image is way less crisp than on 200%, fonts are also more blurry, so I really would like to find a solution for 200% scaling.*

**Original post**

I have a problem with my freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 running with Nvidia GTX 1660 Super.

All the packages are updated to the latest (stable), including kernel 5.8 and Nvidia drivers 455.38.

I am using default Gnome, 4K monitor is connected via a display port cable, HiDPI set to 200%, Night Light is enabled.

On average, every 10 minutes I can see that the *top part* of the screen blinks/flashes, something like a black stripe appears just for a moment.
Flickerings occur in any app: chrome, firefox, or terminal, it does not matter.
VSync, however, works fine and there is no tearing at all.

I tried to google a similar problem and what I have tried so far (without any outcome, unfortunately):

- Changed kernel (5.4 -> 5.8) and NVidia drivers (440 -> 450 -> 455)
- Blacklisted nouveau

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf 
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

- Enabled Force full composition pipeline in Nvidia settings. It still flickered, but I had like 20 fps on the desktop. Saw the flickering immediately, disabled again.
- Tried disabling VSync - no effect.
- Tried disabling "Allow Flipping" setting - no effect.
- Changed Auto performance mode to Prefer Performance - no effect.

What are the other options? I like the system very much, but this small issue just drives me crazy.

Fun fact: it seems to not happen during Zoom full desktop screen sharing.

Cheers.

**Edit 1**

Sample slo-mo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuxMZlJs0uE&feature=youtu.be

You can see that the top part of the screen turns black for a moment.

**Edit 2**

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Thu Dec 17 19:52:19 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.38       Driver Version: 455.38       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:2D:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 28%   32C    P8    14W / 125W |   1868MiB /  5941MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1137      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                101MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1963      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                708MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2093      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              242MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     54184      G   ...AAAAAAAA== --shared-files      699MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     54258      G   ...AAAAAAAA== --shared-files       64MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    106792      G   /opt/zoom/zoom                     34MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux abyss 5.8.0-33-generic #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 17:01:13 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Have you applied the latest firmware updates from your PC vendor?

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for the reply, I've added the outputs

Comment: @ubfan1 thanks for the reply. I've updated my motherboard bios to the latest stable before putting the CPU in (it is a new rig). GPU has stock firmware.

Comment: It seems like the problem is there only with Scaling set to 200%. If I use Fractional scaling and set 150% or 175%, there is no flickering. However, I dislike that that way the image is way less crisp than on 200%, fonts are also more blurry.

Comment: The accepted answer says it is a hardware problem, nothing to do with Ubuntu. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: To the author, please delete the question, as it is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

It is a faulty GPU itself, it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.
The exact same thing happened on Windows and also on the other PC when I tried to run it with my GPU. With different GPU (in my case, 2070), I experience zero issues.

Related thread on NVidia forum: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/user/633273/407871/upper-part-of-the-screen-extremely-randomly-flicke/

TLDR: faulty Hynix video memory chips. It happens sometimes.
For reference, the exact model of my GPU is ASUS PH-GTX1660S-O6G. Will RMA it.